# Увеличение используемой памяти при загрузке файлов используя FileReader API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fileupload

В проекте используется код для загрузки файлов.

Перед загрузкой файл делится на чанки c помощью функции **'prepare'**, далее отсылается запрос на backend с этими чанками и другой инфой (чтобы в случае, когда страница/компьютер крашнулись не нужно было снова делить файл на чанки).

Потом вызывается функция **'upload'** для подготовленного ранее списка чанков, в которой подгружается соответственный чанку кусок файла и отправляется на бекэнд.

**Проблема**: при загрузке больших файлов занимаемая память растет с высокой скоростью. Утечек памяти обнаружить мне не удалось ибо увеличивается не js memory. Мои подозрения падают на FileReader, а в частности, на метод **'onload'**. Так как в нем происходит весь доступ к полученному куску файла. И видимо, память после этого не освобождается. Память растет на Windows'e (mz, chrome). На Linux'е этой проблемы нет вовсе. На mac'е проверить нет возможности.

Чанки подготавливаются рекурсивно, как и загрузка чанка на бекнэнд.

Прикладываю ссылку вдруг у кого есть какие-нибудь идеи.

App.js - простой react-компонент с input'ом.

upload.js - код с функцией для подготовки файла

upload.js - код с функцией для загрузки файла

Достаточно просто добавить файл с размером больше 1gb и открыть task manager.

https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-leakey-l9q4v

Comment: В таком виде вам наверняка помочь не смогут - вопрос слишком общий, слишком  много возможных мест, где может происходить утечка. Я вам рекомендую двигаться от простого к сложному. Сначала проверьте отдельно загрузку больших файлов через `FileReader`. Потом добавьте отправку чанков. Потом добавляйте реакт. Так будет легче выявить причину.